# If statement in .twig file to check if user is logged into Wordpress not rendering expected output to display login button vs. logout button

Tags: wordpress, twig, conditional-statements, timber

I am trying to create a login/logout button for a WordPress site that uses a plugin to only display the content to members who are registered on our WordPress site. According to what I've found I should be able to do that with the timber user object {% if user %}. I am learning as I go with timber/twig for WordPress as I've inherited the website that was originally outsourced and built by an external company.

I found a solution at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257332/how-to-check-in-timber-if-user-is-loggedin/257333 which should work in theory but the browser is only displaying the code inside the else. I don't believe I need to add anything to the controller file to render this but I could be wrong.

```
<nav class="utility-nav">
    <button class="header-search__toggle" aria-label="Toggle Search Form"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
    {% if user %}  
        <a class="header__login-link" href="/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=6e24015e99">Log Out »</a>
    {% else %}    
        <a class="header__login-link" href="/login/">Log In »</a>
    {% endif %}   

</nav>
```

I am expecting to see the Login button when not logged into WordPress and the logout button when logged in. I am only seeing the login button regardless if I'm logged in or not.

Edited to add what's in my controller php file, I did try adding it to the context array with no luck, but if it's a timber object then I shouldn't need to add anything here:

```
    $context = array(
        'logo_url'  => get_site_url(),
        'nav'       => wp_nav_menu( array(
            'container'             => false,
            'menu_class'            => 'nav',
            'echo'                  => false,
            'theme_location'        => 'header',
            )),
        'search'    => get_search_form(false),
        );
    if (empty($context)) return;

    Timber::render('header-hr.twig', $context);
```

Comment: I just tested it on my own sandbox installation and it works as expected... So are you sure the user object is not overwritten somewhere ?

Comment: How does your PHP file look like that renders your Twig view?

Comment: I can't be sure the user object isn't being overwritten, this is a complex site built by a large design company that I took over. Is there something specific I could do a search in the code for?

Comment: I've updated the post above to add the code in my controller file.

Comment: have you tried to print this variable by using {{ user }} ? Don't you need to add it to the $context variable?

Comment: It's a timber object so I wouldn't think it needed to be added to the $context variable, but I did try that and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go a different route and do it all in the controller php:

```
$login = function() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return '<a class="header__login-link" href="/wp-login.php?                action=logout&_wpnonce=6e24015e99">Log Out »</a>';
    } else {
        return ' <a class="header__login-link" href="/login/">Log In »</a>';
    }
};
$context = array(
 'logo_url'     => get_site_url(),
 'nav'      => wp_nav_menu( array(
        'container'             => false,
        'menu_class'            => 'nav',
        'echo'                  => false,
        'theme_location'        => 'header',
    )),
 'search'   => get_search_form(false),
  login'     => $login()
 );
if (empty($context)) return;

Timber::render('header-hr.twig', $context);
```

With this in twig file:

```
<nav class="utility-nav">
    <button class="header-search__toggle" aria-label="Toggle Search Form"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Search</button>
     {{login}}
</nav>
```

All is well and working now!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'm outputting the logout link next to the comments form:

```
<a href="{{ function('wp_logout_url', post.link ) }}">Log out</a>.
```

It'll log the user out and redirect them back to the blogpost.